# IOS What is difference between @"aa" and "aa"?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my code.

```
NString *licencenum = @"1234567890";
NSData*terminalID = [NSData dataWithBytes:"1234567890" length:20];
NSData*terminalID1 = [NSData dataWithBytes:@"1234567890" length:20];
```

What is the difference of terminalID and terminalID1 variable?
I should convert licencenum to terminalID not terminalID1.
Please help.
thanks.

Comment: @"aa"  means its a string value

Comment: Literal C-string (`const char*` "aa" ) vs. literal `NSString` (@"aa").

Comment: Thanks. It great helps.  I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@"string"` is an `NSString` object

`"string"` is a C byte array

`dataWithBytes:length:` takes a C byte array so your first method call is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is answer of my question.
@"string" is an NSString object

"string" is a C byte array

```
NString *licencenum = @"1234567890";
const char*str = [licencenum UTF8String];
NSData*terminalID = [NSData dataWithBytes:str  length:20];
```

Thank you everyone.